# Update data with Struts and Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2

i have to update some rows in database using Hibernate and Struts2:

the method DAO where i put the requete is:

```
public void modifier(String cond) {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
     try{Query query = session.createQuery("Update Processus set selectionne = '1' where"+cond );

        //  query.setString("idproc",idprocessus);
        //  query.setLong("idsi", identifiantsi);
     }catch(HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

     session.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

In my action class where i call the DAO, i specify the cond:

```
public String update(){

cond="id_processus="+checked;



procdao.modifier(cond);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

can u help me it doens't show any error in the console but the row's value don't change!!!!

Comment: When do you execute your query ? In the code you paste, we see you creating an update query but never execute it !

Answer (score 0):

Following code could be helpful: Processus Table name selectionne and idproc are column name

- You need to execute the query
- To check the number of updated rows.

  ```
  public Boolean modifier(String cond) {

  Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
  session.beginTransaction();
  Boolean returnValue = false;
  try {
      Query query = session.createQuery("Update Processus set selectionne = '1' where idproc=:cond");
      query.setString("cond", cond);
      int noOfUpdate = query.executeUpdate();
      returnValue = (noOfUpdate > 0);
  } catch (HibernateException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      session.getTransaction().rollback();
  }
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  return returnValue;
  ```

  }